# How to represent frame data in animation software?

Tags: java

I'm planning on creating a simple 2D frame by frame animation editor with JavaFX. You draw on a canvas, and you can move around the timeline to draw other frames of the animation.

It will be traditional animation - no vectors or bones or any of that.

My main concern right now is how to store the data for every frame.

The most basic way to represent a frame would be to have a nested array of pixels. Like this:

```
Pixel[][] oneFrame = new Pixel[100][100];
```

Would represent one frame drawn on a 100x100 canvas.

If an user works on 1080p resolution, frames would be 1280x720 pixels: almost one million `Pixel` instances (assuming they are all filled with, perhaps, a background color). I am not encouraged by the idea of having a million objects per frame.

Therefore it may not be a good idea to store several frames as arrays of `Pixel` in memory.

How else can I store frame data? It occurs to me that one may store the **steps** taken to create such frame.

```
String[] oneFrame = new String[] {"Stroke, Black, 0, 0, 1280, 720" , "Fill, Green, 0, 720"};
```

Therefore this frame is defined as "First, you make a line from one corner to the other, and then you fill the first half with color green".

That is a lot more lightweight than storing a million things. But a number of disadvantages:

- The more "actions" an artist does, the harder it is for the program to render the frame, since every action is one extra step in the rendering pipeline. Especially when the artists do lots of details.
- If I ever want to have an "export movie" function, the program would have to re-draw every single frame, rather than read any sort of "raw data". I imagine this may cause a big slowdown for larger animations.

---

How should I store frame data?

Comment: Your first frame could be a "full" frame and each subsequent frame could be stored as a "diff" against the previous frame.  I think there are video formats that do something like this.

Comment: Another option would be to store frames as BMPs (effectively an array of pixels anyway) on disk and create an intelligent caching mechanism that loads adjacent frames into memory when the user changes their position in the timeline.

Comment: Unless the `Pixel` stores something more than just a color, you should use a primitive value array such as `int[][]`.

Comment: And maybe you can use [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) to read/write your frames from/to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an animation expert, but here are some ideas you might consider.

1. Yes, 1080p requires around a million pixels per frame.  On a new 64 bit computer with 16 GB of memory, you can keep around 10,000 frames in memory.  The rest you can store on disk.
2. You need to provide a way for the artist to create the animation in layers.  There could be a background layer that moves slowly, a foreground layer that moves a little quicker, and a character layer, where the character moves even quicker.  This gives a 3D effect to the animation.  I believe Disney had a machine that could handle 5 layers of cel back in the 1970's.  You could extend this to 10 or so layers.
3. You could provide a way for the artist to store shapes.  In other words, one drawing for each character that the artist can change slightly for each frame.

I hope this was helpful.